# How to apply bitwise operator to compare a list of objects

Tags: python, bitwise-operators

Suppose I have a long list of objects (say, a list of numpy matrices of bool elements) `foo = [a, b, c]`, that I want to compare with some bitwise operator, to get something like `a | b | c`.

If I could use this bitwise operation as a function, say a `bitwiseor` function, I could simply do this with `bitwiseor(*foo)`.
However, I was not able to find whether the bitwise or can be written in such functional form.

Is there some handy way to handle this kind of problem? Or should I just use a loop to compare all the elements cumulatively?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the functional method in [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.or_) in combination with [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
>>> import operator, functools
>>> functools.reduce(operator.or_, [1, 2, 3])
3
```

Answer (score 2):

`numpy` has a number of functions that support reducing along an axis.  See [`numpy.bitwise_or`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html#numpy.bitwise_or) and [`numpy.bitwise_or.reduce`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce).

```
np.bitwise_or.reduce(your_array)
```